# How to resample a raster snapping to an existing grid?

Tags: r, aggregate, raster, resampling, snapping

I would like to resample a raster from a high resolution to a low resolution (with different extent) in a defined grid cell. Is there a way of using an existing raster file as input for the snapping?

In the raster package, `aggregate` and `resample` seem to be adequate but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Do you need to interpolate onto a different grid, or what?  All `raster` files, so far as I know, define data on a uniform rectangular grid, so "using an existing raster file" would just mean "aggregating or interpolating from MxN to LxK grid."

Comment: The question lacked clarity and had no example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch an external command with `system` and call a `gdal_translate` or `gdal_warp` command. This requires of course the installation of gdal utilities

Comment: Thank for the idea but using gdal_translate does not allow to control the interpolation method. I found the solution using  gdalwarp

Answer (score 7):

You can use `projectRaster` for this if you have a raster in one projection and resolution and you need output in a different particular resolution and projetion.

The `from` argument is your high resolution raster and the `to` argument is your low res raster. Make sure you choose the correct method for aggregation (i.e. `bilinear` for continuous data and `ngb` (nearest neighbour) for categorical data.

```
require( raster )

#  Projection info
proj1 <- CRS("+proj=laea +lon_0=20 +lat_0=5 +ellps=sphere +unit=km +to_meter=1e3")
proj2 <-  CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84")
#  High res raster
r1km <- raster( nrows = 1515 , ncols = 2300 , xmn = -4000 , xmx = -1700 , ymn = -15 , ymx = 1500 , crs = proj1 )

#  Low res raster
r5km <- raster( nrows = 303 , ncols = 460 , xmn = -20 , xmx = -5 , ymn = 4 , ymx = 15 , crs = proj2 )

#  Set some values in high res raster
pts <- rasterToPoints(r1km)
values( r1km ) <-  0.01*pts[,1] + sin(0.02*pi*pts[,2])

#  Reproject using the attributes of the low res raster for output
out <- projectRaster( from = r1km , to = r5km , method = "bilinear" )

#  Plot - extent of second raster doesn't fully cover first so some data is missing
par( mfrow = c(1,2) )
plot( r1km )
plot( out )
```

[image]

If your input and output data are the same except in resolution you can use aggregate...

```
#  If same extent and resolution require use aggregate
r1 <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
r5 <- aggregate( r1 , fact = 5 , method = "bilinear" )
par( mfrow = c(1,2) )
plot( r1 )
plot( r5 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but as my two files are in the same projection, the project does not work. About the aggregate, I cannot specify a file directly in order to snap to the grid, because I don't want to use a "fact" argument but a file?

Comment: @Wraf you should really provide a reproducible example showing what you have done then. I don't think I expend any more effort on this guessing at your requirements.  Please  read [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) and update your question accordingly!

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, not easy to find an answer when not reproducible example is given. But the dataset used isquite big and making such example is not that easy.

Comment: @Wraf Check out how I made an example raster in my post from scratch (or from file). Make some data up to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This solution  works :

```
system(paste("gdalwarp"
,paste(dir_path,"fileHR.tif",sep="")
,paste(dir_path,"fileLR.tif",sep=""),sep=" "))
```

where `dir_path` is the directory where you file are stored, 
`fileHR.tif` is the High resolution file, 
`fileLR.tif` is the low resoltion file.